# PHP SESSION is created but no data is present in it

Tags: php, session, session-variables

**Login.php**

```
$login=Pbkdf2::login($password, $hashpwd, $salt);
if($login)
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['bbzalinusrnmenstr'] =base64_encode($username);
$_SESSION['actualname'] =base64_encode($name);
$_SESSION['useremail'] =base64_encode($email);
$send=array('username'=>$username, 'callingname'=>$name, 'email'=>$email);  
echo json_encode($send); 
exit;
}

else
{
$send=array('error'=>"Mismatching credentails.");  
echo json_encode($send);
}
```

**Index.php**

```
session_start();
$logged=0;
if(isset($_SESSION['bbzalinusrnmenstr']))
{
    $logged=1;
    $username=$_SESSION['bbzalinusrnmenstr'];
    $username=base64_decode($username);
        $actualname=$_SESSION['actualname'];
        $useremail=$_SESSION['useremail'];

        echo "$actualname logged in with $username as his Username and $useremail as his email address";
}
```

This outputs as **logged in with as his Username and as his email address**.

The SESSION 'bbzalinusrnmenstr' is created but no data is in the variable and also in the other two. Why?

Comment: have you place `session_start();` at the beginning of Login.php?

Comment: Not to actually fix the problem, but depending what the system is for, you may want to switch his to their

Comment: @jam6549: I have placed `session_start()` before setting the SESSION variable 'bbzalinusrnmenstr'

Comment: Where are you setting $username?

Comment: @aynber: A few lines before, where I receive using `$_POST` and use it to login. Everything exists but SESSION variable is empty.

Comment: why are you base64 encoding the data? That's pointless work, since you're not sending that data anywhere in a context where it would be need to be protected by base64 encoding.

Comment: @MarcB: I thought of adding some security.

Comment: That's it, I'm changing my name lol! Good day `Fred` ;-) @Fred

Comment: what security? $_SESSION data is kept purely on the server.

Comment: Pardon @MarcB, I was unaware of it. Now removed that. But still it is not working.

Comment: @Fred lol. To be fair it is a good name :p.

Comment: @Fred Hahaha!! Good day `Fred` - Yes it is :) I might change mine to something else, just to avoid the confusion. Cheers ;-) (*Peace*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var_dump` to check the SESSION Variable. If it outputs the data you expected, probably you are doing wrong in your syntax somewhere.

**Example**

`var_dump($_SESSION['bbzalinusrnmenstr']);`

Comment: It outputs similar to this string(18) "My Name".

Comment: It means the SESSION variable exists with data "My Name". You are doing wrong somewhere in your syntax while retrieving the data.